# how to run db2 sql command from a command line?

Tags: command-line, db2

how can I run

- sql command `UPDATE CONTACT
  SET EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'mytestaccount@gmail.com'`
- via command line
- for db2 database
- on linux
- from a shell script file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to be logged into your linux machine with an id that has "db2profile" in it's .profile.

If you are not sure what I'm talking about, look at the .profile of the db2 instance owner (usually db2inst1 unless you changed it during the install). The simplest thing would probably be to log in as the db2 instance owner.

Once you are logged in, type "db2" at the command line. If "db2" is not found, then recheck the .profile stuff.

To execute your sql command type the following at the command line (substitute  with the name of the database you want to connect to):

```
db2 connect to <database name>
db2 UPDATE CONTACT SET EMAIL_ADDRESS = 'mytestaccount@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Yes. If you are doing that, then you probably want to connect to the database as a specific user. In that case use "db2 connect to <database name> user <user name> using <pwd>"

Comment: thank you that. Now I know everything I needed to know to finish my script :-)

Comment: is there a way to connect and execute a command in the same command? similar to this: `"db2 connect to <database name>; SELECT * FROM table;"`