# In a Linux script, is it possible to execute multiple commands in the same process?

Tags: bash, shell, db2, ksh

I have a script that contains:

```
db2 connect to user01
db2 describe indexes for table table_desc
```

What I figure is happening is the process that executes the first line is different from the process that runs the second line. This means that the process that executes the first line gets the connection while the second process that runs the second line has no connection at all. This is verified because I get an error at the second line saying that there exists no database connection.

Is it possible to have the same process run both commands? Or at least a way to "join" the first process to the second?

Comment: This may help: [how to run db2 sql command from a command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5427441/478288)

Comment: The solution in that link doesn't really apply to what I was doing but it definitely put me on the right path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want both instructions to run in the same process you need to write them to a script:

```
$ cat foo.db2
connect to user01
describe indexes for table table_desc
```

and run that script in the `db2` interpreter:

```
db2 -f foo.db2
```

A [Here Document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) might work as well:

```
db2 <<EOF
connect to user01
describe indexes for table table_desc
EOF
```

I can't test that, though, since I currently don't have a DB2 on Linux at hand.

Comment: Both of these work great, thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was looking for.